# Why admob_flutter takes space on screen when there is no ads?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, banner-ads

I am using admob_flutter package for banner , but my issue is ,when app is offline or there is no ads ,  ad space is always their like this screenshot.
How can I solve this ?

[image: Image1]

and this is after ad showing

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try conditional rendering like:

```
isShowAd ? AdBanner() : const SizedBox.shrink()
```

SizedBox.shrink() will not take extra space if there is no ad